# How do you put a face cam in a video editor?

Tags: video, video-editor, video-recording

I am trying to put a face cam in my videos but can't figure out how. I use Openshot, but if there's another editor that works please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also using Openshot and just happened to stumble across a method that seems to work.

1. Right click on the file in the track to be the facecam; select Properties:

   [image: Select Properties]
2. Navigate to the "Layout" tab.
3. Leave the Key Frame as "Start of Clip" and adjust the Height and Width to your desired size (25% seems pretty standard for facecams):

   [image: Steps 2, 3, and 4]
4. Now adjust your "X" and "Y" to position your facecam where you want it on screen. This may take some finagling, and you may want to pop over to the video tab to adjust the Align "Horizontal:" and "Vertical:" to represent the corner you want the facecam in; i.e. if you want your facecam in the bottom left corner, your "Horizontal:" should be "left" and your "Vertical:" should be "bottom":

   [image: The Video Tab]
5. Hit "Apply" and make sure that your facecam looks the way you want it. Once you've got it the way you know you want it to be:
6. Go back to your Properties and into the Layout tab. Change your Key Frame to "End of Clip" and make sure that all of the parameters match what you put in for the "Start of Clip" Key Frame. If you skip this step, the facecam clip will grow/shrink/move/etc. while playing to match the "End of Clip" parameters by the time the clip is over:

   [image: End of Clip]
7. Watch your new video all the way through to make sure it all looks the way you want it to, which you should really be doing anyway.

That's it! I hope that helps you out. Add a comment to this answer if you need a little more clarification on anything or if there's something else you think of that I should add.

Cheers!